# How to retrieve DISTINCT values from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here goes my table values. ( 7 Records )

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
```

I can't post the image as my rep is low. So i am linking it here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFl0u.png

I wrote a query to avoid the last record, but i am still getting the last record. (ALL I NEED IS DISTINCT EMAILS)

```
SELECT DISTINCT CandEmail,CandName,EmployerId,ContNum,IsDeleted,CandPortalId FROM tbl1
WHERE EmployerId = 7 AND IsDeleted = 0
```

The above query still retrieves the same 7 records with last duplicate email record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care which `ContNum` you get, then you can place an aggregate function around that field and then `GROUP BY` the rest:

```
SELECT CandEmail,
  CandName,
  EmployerId,
  MIN(ContNum) ContNum,  -- or you can use MAX()
  IsDeleted,
  CandPortalId 
FROM tbl1
WHERE EmployerId = 7 
  AND IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY CandEmail,
  CandName,
  EmployerId, 
  IsDeleted,
  CandPortalId
```

Or as others have pointed out, you should use aggregate functions on the other fields as well, unless you know for sure there are not different values in those columns:

```
SELECT CandEmail,
  min(CandName) CandName,
  min(EmployerId) EmployerId,
  MIN(ContNum) ContNum,  -- or you can use MAX()
  min(IsDeleted) IsDeleted,
  min(CandPortalId) CandPortalId
FROM tbl1
WHERE EmployerId = 7 
  AND IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY CandEmail
```

Comment: This won't just return distinct emails? It will return distinct combinations of `CandEmail,  CandName, CandPortalId ` (the where clause ensures only one  `EmployerId,   IsDeleted` matches anyway)

Comment: @MartinSmith based on the data sample the item that had the multiple values was the `ContNum` column, so placing I placed the aggregate on the field that would cause the issue.

Comment: Didn't look at the sample data. If that is the case then the OP should read up on normalisation and functional dependencies. Looks like they need a separate candidate table.

Comment: @bluefeet. Seems like a dangerous assumption, based on such a small sample.

Comment: @user1742429 my suggestion would be to use @timschmelter's answer it is much cleaner and easier to implement. You can even use the `row_number()` without the `with` clause

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with `OVER` clause:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT CandEmail,CandName,EmployerId,ContNum,IsDeleted,CandPortalId
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CandEmail ORDER BY ContNum DESC)
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT CandEmail,CandName,EmployerId,ContNum,IsDeleted,CandPortalId
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

[OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the
>   associated window function is applied. That is, the OVER clause
>   defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result
>   set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the
>   window.

Comment: much cleaner, than the `GROUP BY` version.

Comment: Hi i tried your query too and it worked but records with IsDeleted = 1 gets showed too ? So in that case i added this statement to the end SELECT CandEmail,CandName,EmployerId,ContNum,IsDeleted,CandPortalId
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 AND IsDeleted=0 . Is this right ? Thanks

Comment: @user1742429: Yes, i missed that part. But it would be cleaner if you would at it in the first place in the CTE. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @user1742429 you should move your acceptance of the answer to this one. It is a better answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` :--

```
  SELECT CandEmail, MAX(CandName), MAX(EmployerId), MAX(ContNum), MAX(IsDeleted),          MAX(CandPortalId)
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE EmployerId = 7 AND IsDeleted = 0
  GROUP BY CandEmail
```

Comment: Sorry i need all the records :(

Comment: then join again to table after this result, but if any CantNum or CandPortalId is distinct you'll get more records

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CandEmail, 
       MAX(CandName), 
       7 [EmployerId], 
       MAX(ContNum), 
       0 [IsDeleted], 
       MAX(CandPortalId)
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  EmployerId = 7 AND IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY CandEmail
```